# SQLite: Ordering my select results

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with unique usernames and a bunch of string data I am keeping track of. Each user will have 1000 rows and when I select them I want to return them in the order they were added. Is the following code a necessary and correct way of doing this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  username TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  col1 TEXT,
  col2 TEXT,
  ...
  order_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX foo_order_index ON foo(order_id);

SELECT * FROM foo where username = 'bar' ORDER BY order_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each user will have 1000 rows, then username should not be the primary key.  One option is to use the int identity column which all tables have (which optimizes I/O reads since it's typically stored in that order).

Read under "RowIds and the Integer Primary Key"  @ http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

> The data for each table in SQLite is stored as a B-Tree structure
>   containing an entry for each table row, using the rowid value as the
>   key. This means that retrieving or sorting records by rowid is fast.

Because it's stored in that order in the B-tree structure, it should be fast to order by the int primary key.  **Make sure it's an alias for rowid though - more in that article.**

Also, if you're going to be doing queries where username = 'bob', you should consider an index on the username column - especially there's going to be many users which makes the index effective because of high selectivity.  In contrast, adding an index on a column with values like 1 and 0 only leads to low selectivity and renders the index very ineffective.  So, if you have 3 users :) it's not worth it.

Comment: I see rowid is automatically an autoincrementing 'primary key' if no primary key is specified. I removed PRIMARY KEY and order_id from the table and do a select * from table order by rowid and get what I wanted! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add a DateAdded field and default it to the date/time the row was added and sort on that.

If you absolutely must use the order_ID, which I don't suggest. Then at least make it an identity column. The reason I advise against this is because you are relying on side affects to do your sorting and it will make your code harder to read.

Comment: Is the reason you don't recommend it due to the upper bounds of an int?

Comment: No. If you want to track the entry date, you would use a date field named appropriately. Model it explicitly after what you are tracking an OrderID should be just a unique ID not a dual purpose way to get the chronology of orders.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the order_id column & index entirely (unless you need them for something other than this sorting).

SQLite tables always have a integer primary key - in this case, your username column has silently been made a unique key, so the table only has the one integer primary key. The key column is called rowid. For your sorting purpose, you'll want to explicitly make it AUTOINCREMENT so that every row always has a higher rowid than older rows.

You probably want to read http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
   rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   username TEXT UNIQUE KEY,
   ...
```

Then your select becomes

```
 select * from foo order by rowed;
```

One advantage of this approach is that you're re-using the index SQLite will already be placing on your table. A date or order_id column is going to mean an extra index, which is just overhead here.