# Android context menu no longer appearing in emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, contextmenu

I'm building an Android app that uses a context menu on a list from a database. I had it all working fine, moved on to building a section of the app that uses maps, and now (while I've switched to the level 10 android google emulator) I have had two issues spring up. The first was fixed quickly enough, but my context menus no longer appear. I don't know if it's something to do with the change in emulator, but here's my code:

In onCreate we have:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

datasource = new DiaryDataSource(this);
datasource.open();

List<DiaryEntry> values = datasource.getAllDiaryEntries();

DiaryScheduleAdapter adapter = new DiaryScheduleAdapter(this,values);
setListAdapter(adapter);

registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

Then in my class that extends ArrayAdapter we have:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        DiaryEntry diaryEntry = getItem(position);

        View v = convertView;
        if ( v == null ) 
        {
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.diary_schedule, null);
        }

**** TextViews etc ****

        v.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));

        return v;
```

And then the onCreateContextMenu:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.diary_context_menu, menu);
}
```

Also, for the normal press click listener I use this:

```
private class OnItemClickListener implements OnClickListener
{           
    private int mPosition;

    OnItemClickListener(int position)
    {
        mPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        **** various bits of code to set up intent ****

        startActivity(descIntent);
    }               
}
```

And then the onContextItemSelected method below that, but I don't get that far. Again, I'm sure I made no changes to the code, but the long click now does nothing. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code for onLongClick, getListView, etc and any logcat errors as well.

Comment: I don't have any onLongClick code and don't get any errors. I a click listener - 'v.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));' - as you can also just click on each list item as well. But again, just this code was enough for it to work a week ago... Should I add some onLongClick code?

Comment: Not specifically, I wanted to make sure there wasn't conflicting code, since what you have provided looks fine. Have you cleaned your project recently? Does adding `super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);` to OnCreateContextMenu help?

Comment: Nope - no change. It's really weird that things have randomly stopped working. The other thing was a bit of SQL that it decided it no longer liked.. I'm gonna try installing the apk file onto my phone and see if it's the emulator that's not working

Comment: You can also select "Wipe User Data" when launching your AVD, if only to make you feel better. Have you confirmed that `onCreateContextMenu()` is even called?

Comment: Hmm after installing the apk file and trying to run it, I get the message 'application not installed'.. I may be missing something on installing the app, but that can wait. Any other ideas? I might actually try shutting my comp down and restarting!

Comment: onCreateContextMenu() is no longer being called - that seems to be the problem but I've no idea why it's no longer being called..

Comment: A reboot won't hurt. If you post more of your code I might be able to find something, but at the moment I have no idea what is trumping your context menu... Sorry.

Comment: I've added some more code at the top - hopefully that will help. In the meantime I'll shut down - fingers crossed!

Comment: I think I found it, give me a minute to type it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add the line of code below to my getView method:

```
convertView.setLongClickable(true);
```

Thanks again to Sam for lots of useful input

Answer (score 1):

**Rewrite** (Some days I shouldn't attempt to write code outside an IDE)

Here is a trivial example of what I was trying to say:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Shoes");
        list.add("Socks");
        list.add("Sandals");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        registerForContextMenu(listView);
    }   

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        Log.v("Main", "Create Menu");
    }

    protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.v("Main", "Item Click");
    }
}
```

It sounds like you want the context menu to be specific for each row, in that case I would use the `menuInfo`.

Comment: Yep it's a ListView activity. I think this sounds right. So basically it's a list where if you click on an item it takes you to another activity, taking details of that item with it (using OnItemClickListener). And if you long press you get a context menu for editing/deleting the list item. At the moment just the normal click works. Do I want to make a separate line of code to the one I already have or just have the one that covers both? I'll start playing! Oh and I have a separate blank 'onClick(View v)' method in case that makes a difference.

Comment: I forgot the point of mentioning all that: make sure that however you handle the item click on each row that it doesn't somehow absorb you long clicks.

Comment: Sorry I'm still pretty rubbish with Android - it takes a while to get pretty much anything working..

Comment: I'm afraid I'm having serious trouble incorporating this into my code. I think because my activity extends ListActivity, and uses List values, with no ListView mentioned in the activity at any point, it works slightly differently from most of the examples I've come across. I just cannot understand why it stopped working...

Comment: I switched my Activity example to a ListActivity. Notice the `onListItemClick()` function, this is what I was trying to tell you about. Also, in onListItemClick you should test whether the contextMenu is visible or not so you don't execute _both_ functions on a long click.

Comment: I've just stumbled across a solution on another forum. All it needed was to insert 'v.setLongClickable(true);' into the getView method. Again, I have absolutely no idea how it worked in the first place if this line had to be in there... Anyway, thanks for all your help Sam - it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: Glad you found an answer. Good luck!

Comment: Well on another note the other problem I spoke of is killing me now. It stopped liking 'autoincrement' for an id and wouldn't because of it, but then it didnt insert an id. now i've put the code back in and it still isnt inserting ids.. Something's happened here that's messing it all up but god knows what...

Comment: Are you trying to use "autoincrement" as a column's characteristic or as an column name? Post a new question, bonus points for formatting your create statement(s) like [this one.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028415/sqlite-ordering-my-select-results)

Comment: It's ok I've sorted it. Yeah I had autoincrement for the id column, but got rid and had to make a couple of changes because I'd switched to a new device that I hadn't created the DB on yet (because I'd switched to google API to use maps). Still, quite why it worked first time round is a mystery..!